# Manatee Trello List All Organisations

Tags: trello, manatee.trello

I've been playing with Manatee.Trello and it is soooo awesome. Thank you Gregsdennis.

I can list the names of all of my open boards, along with their organisation, like so:

```
Dim myBoards = New Search(SearchFor.IsOpen, 100, SearchModelType.Boards)

For Each myBoard As Board In myBoards.Boards
    Response.Write(myBoard.Name & " - " & myBoard.Organization.Name & "<br/>")
Next
```

However, if I try the same with Organisations, the resulting count is always 0:

```
Dim myOrganisations = New Search(SearchFor.IsOpen, 20, SearchModelType.Organizations)

Response.Write(myOrganisations.Organizations.Count) 'this is 0

For Each myOrganisation As Organization In myOrganisations.Organizations
    Response.Write(myOrganisation.Name)
Next
' nothing written out
```

Does anyone have any ideas please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using my library!  I have recently had similar questions asked regarding the search, and it seems the issue (if it can be called that) is at Trello's end.

They say that some of the search criteria are set up to only return cards.  See the Oct 26 (2015) response by Stephen Fluin on their API dev board.

> Yes, there are a number of modifiers that restrict the results set to cards, including edited created is:archived and more.

It's likely that `is:open` (how you would add the criteria on their site) is one of those.

This seems to be by design since Organizations (now they're called *Teams*) can't be closed, only deleted.  Boards can be closed, lists and cards can be archived.  I expect these would respond well to the `is:open` search.

Instead of performing a search, try simply enumerating the `Member.Organizations` property (use `Member.Me.Organizations` for the user who owns the token).  This will list all of the organizations to which the user belongs.  [*This is dead now. See **Edit 1.***] Also, there are a number of [extension methods](https://bitbucket.org/gregsdennis/manatee.trello/src/907a22cfcb46f0b410a8493665d5e87a970ccee0/Manatee.Trello/Extensions/CollectionExtensions.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) that can be used on these properties to filter the results.

**Edit 1**

As of version 3.0, the filtering functionality has been moved from an extension method to a new `Filter` property on all collections.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, @gregsdennis. As you suggested, the Member.Me.Organisations worked perfectly.

Comment: Links are dead :(

Comment: Thanks. Added in the quote and new edit regarding the code link.

Answer (score 2):

For the record the following, straightforward code did exactly what I wanted, as suggested by @gregsdennis

```
Dim orgs = Member.Me.Organizations

For Each org As Organization In orgs
    Response.Write(org.Name)
Next
```

I'm making a simple Job Queue that shows the first card from any selected board to keep me focussed by not getting distracted by all my other cards and just picking the easiest thing to do!